# Expand/Collapse Content on a Webpage [ also load content on click ]

Tags: jquery

I'm making a site that has different panoramas on one page

made with pano2vr gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr.php

The problem is that I want to hide each panorama in an expandable section. so the user can scroll down and then open up the one they want.

I've been trying different expand/collapse codes, such as this one

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/expand.html

and this

http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Collapse/

(the reason i've chose these is that they have smooth opening animations, a graphic that changes to show if its open or closed and you can have more than one open at a time [non-accordion style])

However the first issue is the panoramas don't load if they are in a collapsed section.
(if I use the 2nd script it has cookies and remembers if a section was open, if I open the section with the panorama in and refresh the page then it will load in)

also I don't want them (the panoramas/content inside the expandable sections)to load in when you open the page, as each one can be 5mb+, so I need some way of loading the content in the section when you expand it. (unfortunately the panoramas both flash and html5 autoload)

This is the code I use to load a panorama on a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // hide URL field on the iPhone/iPod touch
        function hideUrlBar() {

            if (window.pageYOffset==0) {
                window.scrollTo(0, 1);
                // repeat every second for slow rendering pages
                setTimeout(function() { hideUrlBar(); }, 3000);

            }
        }
    </script>
```

and

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="pano2vr_player.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="skin.js">
    </script>
    <div id="container" style="width:960px;height:540px;">
    This content requires HTML5/CSS3, WebGL, or Adobe Flash Player Version 9 or higher.
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // create the panorama player with the container
        pano=new pano2vrPlayer("container");
        // add the skin object
        skin=new pano2vrSkin(pano);
        // load the configuration
        pano.readConfigUrl("some_panorama_name.xml");
        // hide the URL bar on the iPhone
        hideUrlBar();

    </script>
```

I've seen some stuff with ajax but I'm unsure how to tie it all into jQuery to make this work.

I did also think that I could just have an image in the hidden sections which would say, click here to load panorama, then use some code to swap out the image for the panorama, but I don't know how I'd do that? ajax? iframe?

Thanks for reading this far! I wanted to make sure I covered everything before posting.

Comment: I have tried putting the content into an iframe and having an image saying click here to load panorama, however when it loads the panorama the fullscreen option doesn't work as it tries to fullscreen within its own iframe, and not the browser window. Silly html5

Comment: Think i might of found a solution:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/4/5/Collapsible-content-and-Ajax-loading-with-jQuery-Mobile

Comment: the above didn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Those plugins most likely offer events that you can hook into.  If so you can add an event handler to the "onExpand" (I'm assuming) event and dynamically add the panorama image using jQuery's append() and appendTo() functions.  So when the collapse panel is expanded add the image tag:

```
$("<img src='mypanorama.jpg' id='panorama1' />").appendTo("#collapsePanel1");
```

and then when it is collapsed remove the image tag (by id):

```
$("#panorama1").remove();
```

Comment: Hey robbymurphy, 
Thanks for the response, I understand what you're saying, in terms of jQuery being flexible. however I'm just a photographer. The last time I did any website work was back in 2006 and then it was just tables.

The only thing I know is that I need to link to a .js file for jQuery to work.

So I don't know how to implement what you've suggested.